# Yii2 Missing required parameters: slug (Bad Request (#400))

Tags: php, yii2, http-status-code-404, slug

Пишу блог. Использую zabachok\behaviors\SluggableBehavior

Модель:

```
use zabachok\behaviors\SluggableBehavior;
  public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            [
                'class' => SluggableBehavior::className(),
                'attribute' => 'title'
            ]
        ];
    }
```

В rules нет слага.

Контроллер:

```
public function actionView($slug)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModelBySlug($slug),
        ]);
    }
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Article();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'slug' => $model->slug]);
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
    protected function findModelBySlug($slug)
    {
        if (($model = Article::findOne(['slug' => $slug])) !== null) {
            return $model;
        }

        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
```

config/web:

```
'urlManager' => [
            ...
            'rules' => [
                '<alias:\w+>' => 'site/<alias>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                'article/view/<slug:\w+>' => 'article/view',
                'category/view/<slug:\w+>' => 'category/view'
            ],
        ],
```

...

view:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'id',
            'title',
            'description:ntext',
            'created_by',
            'created_at:relativeTime',
            [
                'attribute' => 'status',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'value' => function ($data) {
                    return $data->status
                        ? '<span class="text-success">Опубликовано</span>'
                        : '<span class="text-danger">Удалено</span>';
                }
            ],
            'category_id',
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                'template'=>'{view} {update} {delete}',
                'buttons'=>[
                    'view' => function ($url, $model) {
                        return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>', 'view/'.$model->slug);
                    }
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]); ?>
```

При попытке сохранить изменения в статье - выдаёт ошибку и ссылка содержит только id 'http://yiiblog.dev/article/view?id=1'

Answer (score 0):

Эта ошибка возникает не при сохранении, а при попытке перейти на роут `/article/view?id=1`, так как `actionView($slug)` ожидает `slug`, а не `id`.

Проверь базу данных на наличие новой статьи и, если она там есть, скопируй её `slug` и перейди по роуту `/article/view/{your_slug}`.

Comment: По роуту 404 ошибка

Answer (score 0):

Для построения корректного маршрута в view нужно построить маршрут таким образом:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        ...
return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>', 'view/?slug='.$model->slug);
                    }
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]); ?>
```